# Windows Phone 8 & Html5 video : Is it possible to play video inline in webpage

Tags: html, mobile, video, windows-phone-8

I want to play a video which is embedded on a webpage. On Windows phone however, first of all the video isn't played inline, but downloaded and played apart from the webpage. Secondly, the 'oncanplaythrough' event doesn't seem to fire?

```
<video id="introVideo" preload="auto" oncanplaythrough="alert('can play');this.play()">
    <source src="videos/Intro.mp4" type="video/mp4"/></source>
    Your browser doesn't support html5 video<br />
</video>
```

Is it possible to play a html5 video inline on WP8, and if so, how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is, unfortunately, [not possible on WP8](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/11/08/internet-explorer-10-brings-html5-to-windows-phone-8-in-a-big-way.aspx):

> **Differences with Windows 8**
>
> There are some minor differences between Internet Explorer 10 for Windows 8 and Internet Explorer 10 for Windows Phone that you need to be aware of. Internet Explorer 10 for Windows Phone does not support the following:
>
> - Inline video

**Update**:

With the upcoming release of Windows Phone 8.1, it is highly likely IE11 Mobile will support inline HTML5 video. This was demonstrated [in a leaked WP8.1 SDK](http://www.wpcentral.com/developers-leak-new-features-windows-phone-81-sdk).

Comment: Confirmed by Patrick Lauke, IE 11 on WP8.1 can play HTML5 video inline. See [his tweet](https://twitter.com/patrick_h_lauke/status/456032708322680832) for evidence

Comment: Sorry to intrude, as I am not sure this would be a valid SO question, but why would I go thru the trouble of using a player that supports Silverlight when IE on most modern Windows phones can play MP4/H.264 on an HTML5 player?