# WebM video format on MediaElement (Windows Phone 8)

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is it possible to play webm video on the mediaelement.  I know in WP7 you can't but how about WP8.  What alternatives do I have.  For now I'm thinking converting the videos to mp4 or check if there is a decoder or something for it.

Answer (score 0):

According to this  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462087%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
and this 
[Windows Phone 8 & Html5 video : Is it possible to play video inline in webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744568/windows-phone-8-html5-video-is-it-possible-to-play-video-inline-in-webpage)
 you can't

But for example this app http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/getthemall/b35d35ae-17c9-44a1-b751-287e347045cb can play it